# Even and Odd number without modulus operator in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wanted to calculate `EVEN` and `ODD` number without using `modulus` operator `(%)`.

With `modulus` operator code is below:

```
def even_odd(number)
  if number % 2 ==  0 
    puts "Even Number" 
  else
    puts 'Odd Number'
  end
end

even_odd(5)
=> Odd Number
even_odd(4)
=> Even Number
```

Comment: `1.odd?`, `2.even?` already exist. Why though?

Comment: Please edit to tell us what `number.class` is. I suspect it is `Integer` but note there is the method [Numeric#%](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Numeric.html#method-i-25).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily by using [Integer#even?](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F) or [Integer#odd?](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F):

```
def even_odd(number)
  if number.even? 
    'Even Number'
  else
    'Odd Number'
  end
end

puts even_odd(5)
puts even_odd(4)
```

Some notes on programming style:

- You should never mix calculation and input/output. This makes your code very hard to test. Here, I removed the printing from the calculation and this makes it very easy to test: I can just call the method and check its return value: `even_odd(5) == 'Odd Number'`
- Consistency is important. You used double quotes for one string and single quotes for the other string. Everybody who reads your code, will now waste precious time trying to figure out what you want to convey with that. Because if two things are different, then they surely must be different for a reason, and there is something important you want to tell the reader with that.
- This is last point is especially true for strings, since single-quoted string literals and double-quoted string literals actually *have* different behavior, so it is even more confusing why you use single quotes in one case and double quotes in the other case. I personally prefer single quotes and only use double quotes if I actually want to make use of escape sequences or string interpolation, or if the string includes a single quote as its content.

Comment: A second reason to separate the calculation from `puts`ing the result is to make the method more versatile, for possible use elsewhere in one’s code.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `&` operator, like so:

```
def even_odd(number)
  if number & 1 ==  0 
    puts "Even Number" 
  else
    puts 'Odd Number'
  end
end

even_odd(5)
=> Odd Number
even_odd(4)
=> Even Number
```

**Edit:**
As @ndnenkov has suggested in comments, you can use `even?` or `odd?` like so:

```
def even_odd(number)
  if number.even?()
    puts "Even Number" 
  else
    puts 'Odd Number'
  end
end

even_odd(5)
=> Odd Number
even_odd(4)
=> Even Number
```

Comment: what does ```& 1```do? like how does it act?

Comment: @DanielK: It calls the method [`Integer#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-26) passing `1` as an argument.

Comment: As for how to Google it, it's called the `bitwise and` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial [odd and even](https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/16995/even-and-odd-numbers).

```
a = 4
a.odd? # => true
a.even? # => false
```